# tomcat 7 + freebsd 7.2 (32bits) multithread app throws OutOfMemoryError: could not create native thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tomcat, out-of-memory

Situation: there is server based on freebsd 7.2 with tomcat 7 installed. Tomcat 7 runs huge multithread server application which reads data through ServerSocket from some different devices. So there is some listener threads for each port for different devices. When device is authorized listener creates new thread that collects data from authorized device (1 device per thread), incoming data not so huge by the way. Also there is web socket listener for clients, it works same way - 1 thread per client. This all worked really good until number of devices was increased from 200 to 1500 (number of clients rised too, near 300).
Ideally process must work with more than 3000 active threads, but it crushes.

Here is code for thread pool on which application based.

```
public class MultiThreadPool {

private static final int INITIAL_POOL_SIZE = 1250;
private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
private final ThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(INITIAL_POOL_SIZE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, queue, new ThreadFactory() {

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread th = new Thread(r);
        //th.setDaemon(true);
        th.setContextClassLoader(null);
        th.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                //t.setDaemon(true);
                //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        });
        return th;
    }
});

private static class SingletonHolder {

    private final static MultiThreadPool instance = new MultiThreadPool();
}

private static MultiThreadPool getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolder.instance;
}

public MultiThreadPool() {
}

public static void initPool() {
    getInstance();
}

public static void executeRunnable(Runnable r) {
    try {
        getInstance().exec.execute(r);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        System.out.println("** Out of memory: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void stopPool() {
    getInstance().exec.shutdownNow();
    //getInstance().executor.shutdownNow();
}
}
```

All threads are running through ExecuteRunnable(Runnable r) procedure. Increasing of INITIAL_POOL_SIZE (core size for ThreadPoolExecutor) to 1300 for example causes OutOfMemoryError: could not create native thread. Also if INITIAL_POOL_SIZE stays at 1250, so another threads in queue does not work at all until some of core threads are not complete. And this causes that clients does not work too in both situations.

I've already tried to manipulate JVM using -Xss, -server, -Xms, -Xmx, -Xss, perm size etc.
Even OS hard limits was increased using loader.conf and login.conf. But all of these don't help very much or make it worse. May be there are another limits in freebsd which can be increased by deploying Kernel with another configuration?

Anyway, I need to increase ammount of active threads on server to process full set of devices and clients. By the way devices sends data every 5 secods at least.

Please, show me the right way to fix this problem!

PS: This app was built by another guy, so I cant say a lot about it, because it's really huge. But I will try to provide you with more information if you'll need this.

Answer (score 0):

The OS seems to be limited to the number of threads it can create regardless of memory.  Depending on what OS you're on check to see the limit and also check to see if you can increase the number.

For instance for mac you check via

```
sysctl kern.num_threads
kern.num_threads: 10240
```

For linux

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
3500
```

and so forth.

You can address this two ways.

1. Increase the number
2. Use a pool of threads instead of creating thousands of them (generally I like idea better).

Comment: Third way: use NIO with Tomcat 8. NIO decouples I/O tasks from threads (1 thread can handle I/O tasks for many connections, especially usefull when data is send in intervals). Tomcat 8 is currently in beta but promises good support for using NIO in a comfortable manner. One thread per connection is limited in scalability: the OS has a limit on the amount of threads that can be managed efficiently (allthough for freebsd that limit is probably high).